# Sprite array list never works! Need help understanding how to create arrays of class instances in JAVA

Tags: java, android, arrays, graphics, sprite

// Particle Stuct Instance
    private Sprite[] mParticles = new Sprite[10];

```
/// Particle emitter Properties
private Context mContext;

private int mPositionX, mPositionY, mWidth, mHeight, mNumParticles;


private Rect srcRect, dstRect;

/*** Constructor ! ***/
public ParticleEmitter(Context c, Sprite spriteImage, int num_particles) {

    super(c);
    mContext = c;

    Sprite[] Particles = new Sprite[10];

    Particles[0] = new Sprite(mContext, R.drawable.icon);

//  mParticles = spriteImage;
    //mParticles[num_particles].InitAttributes(c, R.drawable.icon);

    // Allocate Particles instances and copy into mParticle member
    //mParticles = new Sprite[num_particles];
 //   Sprite sprite1 =  new Sprite(mContext, R.drawable.icon);
//    Sprite sprite2 =  new Sprite(mContext, R.drawable.icon);

  //  mParticles[0] = spriteImage;
   // mParticles[1] =  sprite2;
/*  for(int i = 0; i < num_particles; i++)
    {
       mParticles[i].InitAttributes(mContext, R.drawable.icon);
       mParticles[i].setXPosition(i);
    }  */

//   mParticles[0].InitAttributes(mContext, R.drawable.icon);


    // nullify our positioning attributes
    mPositionX = mPositionY = 0;

}
```

Comment: Your initialization seems to be okay, what problems do you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `new Sprite[10]` is creates an array of ten Sprite references, which are all equal to `null` by default.  It does not create any new Sprite objects.  After this, you'll likely want to create a new Sprite object to stick in each of these ten places.  For example:

```
Sprite[] rgSprite = new Sprite[10];
for (int i = 0; i < rgSprite.length; i++) {
    rgSprite[i] = new Sprite(mContext, R.drawable.icon);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys! Gunslingers you were indeed correct. However, I ended up using Java generics like List and ArrayList to manage my instances ( which worked brilliantly for my needs ). Example: 

// Particle  Instance Array stucture using Generics <br>
 private List<Sprite> mParticles = new ArrayList<Sprite>(10);

... Then I would just iterate through the list instantiating them with new. Thanks for the help.